# Lie symmetries of differential equation and ladder operators

Tags: symmetry, harmonic-oscillator, group-theory, lie-algebra, differential-equations

There is literature on the lie symmetries of quantum harmonic oscillator differential equation. The generators satisfy certain lie algebra.
On the other hand, we have ladder operator method. The relevant operators satisfy some lie algebra.
I was interested in knowing if there might be some connection with the two approaches. Is there some relation between the two lie algebras. Cause if there is, it might help me explain ladder operator method better.